# Где расположен пользовательский орфографический словарь в linux-системах?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, firefox

Подскажите пожалуйста, где находится пользовательский словарь, в который можно добавлять новые слова для проверки орфографии в браузерах?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для моего огнелиса-52.8.0 это `~/.mozilla/firefox/blev4g1s.default/persdict.dat`

Метод определения для всех остальных:

1. Нажать ладонью на клавиатуру (у меня вылезло `yutyyvuyulp`).
2. Добавить слово в словарь.
3. `grep`'нуть по данному слову домашний каталог (или какую-то его часть):

   ```
   grep -r 'yutyyvuyulp' ~
   ```